# IndentationError: expected an indented block in requests.adapter

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

This is my code:

```
import pandas_datareader
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

```
 File "C:\Users\58949566886849568\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\av\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
  File "C:\Users\58949566886849568\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\58949566886849568\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
    from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options
  File "C:\Users\58949566886849568\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import sessions
  File "C:\Users\58949566886849568\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .adapters import HTTPAdapter
  File "C:\Users\58949566886849568\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 453
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What is the issue?

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block` - yes, you need to indent your Python code correctly.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - except that error is in requests.adapter, not user code.

Comment: this are just module imports there is nothing to indent.

Comment: My only guess is that your requests package has been corrupted. You could try reinstalling. Which operating system? How did you install python and requests? You can find the file with `import requests;print(requests.__file__)` and see what it looks like. Personally, I'd pull the requests source repo and compare with what I have on disk. Maybe python 2 requests install on python 3?

Comment: how can i fix the error from the adapter?kindly.  i just installed the modules. ?kindly

Comment: @tdelaney Ah my bad - botched requests package?

Comment: I just found out my requests module was corrupted. Thanks. solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `requests` package seems to be corrupted as there seem to be issues within the package itself.

Try reinstalling the package:

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests
```